# Difference between class area and heap

Tags: java, memory, jvm

The JVM allocates these areas in memory:
Class(Method) Area, Heap, Stack, Program counter Register, Native method stack.

I know that heap is used to store objects and stack is used to store local variables and partial results.
According to definition,
Class(Method) Area stores per-class structures such as the runtime constant pool, field and method data, the code for methods. But I really don't understand the difference.

Can anyone please explain the difference between Class area and Heap?

Comment: There needs to be a space to store all of the meta-data about classes, etc. These aren't data in your application, but they need to be stored all the same.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Java 6 stores all the constant pool and Class information in the Perm Gen

Java 7 only stores the class information in the Perm Gen. The String literal pool is on the heap.

Java 8 has no Perm Gen. The literal pools and class information are on the heap.

You have explained the difference.  Class structures like methods are stored in perm gen.  The data in each instance is stored in the heap.

They were separated as these types of data have very different lifecycles e.g. Objects are typically short lived and classes are typically very long lived.

AFAIK They are removing it because too many developers found it confusing.

Comment: With Java 8, is it safe to say that there nothing like class area now as class definitions are also stored on heap.

Comment: @BalkrishanNagpal it safe to say that Metaspace us just like Perm Hen but with a different name and tuned differently. It does the same thing. There is no code on the heap.

Answer (score 7):

The class (method) area stores *code* - that's the code of your program. The heap stores object instances. For example:

```
public void MakeSomeFruit(){

   Fruit myFruit=new Fruit();

}
```

- The MakeSomeFruit code is stored in the class area.
- When executed, the actual Fruit instance it creates is stored in the Heap.
- When executed, the myFruit *reference* variable is stored on the stack. That's just a number which points at the location of the instance in memory - an address.